# How does LifecycleScope convert stateFlow to cold stream?

Tags: android, coroutine

StateFlow is a hot flow, but when we use it in an Android view, the LifecycleScope converts it to a cold stream.

I want to know how this happens, tks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that the LifecycleScope is tied to the lifecycle of the view, and when the view is destroyed, the scope is also destroyed. This ensures that any resources associated with the scope are properly cleaned up and not leaked.